# Libgdx - Font that is smotth uses mega RAM

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a viewport (360x640), but if I render fonts on that they are ugly. So I made higher size's and downscaled them. But now they go disoriented. (size == 30)

I made a 4x bigger viewport then so I didn't need to downscale them. But now my game instead of taking 15mb ram takes up 50mb. (size == 120)

And this is not acceptable. That my textures take 30x less ram than shitty 3 TTFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems#world-coordinates.
Use 2 viewports:

- One which is near pixel perfect (around the same as the screen resolution of your reference target device), which you use only for the GUI like labels, buttons, etc.
- And one which fits your game logic best (although 360x640 gives the impression you are using banana units (imaginary pixels), which you shouldn't do) and you only for rendering game objects and such.

Either way, the size of your assets (either on disk, in RAM or in VRAM) are not in any way related to the size of your viewport: when you change the size of your viewport then you should *not* scale your assets. The size of your assets should be around the same size as they are when they are projected on the screen. So it doesn't matter whether you use a viewport of 3 by 5 *meters* or a viewport 1440 by 2560 *bananas*. What matters is the size in *pixels* on the actual screen (e.g. take a screenshot and measure it). The size of the assets should be around that same size for best results.

If that means that you need a very large font, e.g. because you use a reference target device with a very high resolution (e.g. Retina Display), then that's how it is. You could work around that in several ways, e.g. by rendering to a smaller FBO, using texture filtering, etc. But reality is that devices with such large resolutions are equipped with at least enough memory to hold the assets for such resolution. So, in that case using more memory isn't really an issue.

If you like to target multiple resolutions which have different restrictions on the asset size then you can use multiple assets sets. For example by using `ResolutionFileHandleResolver`.

Although not related to your question, note that `BitmapFont` by default assumes a near pixel perfect projection and therefor uses integer positions to prevent aliasing. If you really don't want use a near pixel perfect projection then you disable that using the `BitmapFont#setUseIntegerPositions` method.

Comment: Well if I target Retina Display, I need to render huge fonts... But if I downscale those, they look ugly. Well at least it happend now, when I used 360x640 bananas... Or am I missing a point here? I was also wondering what would happen if I used a ScreenViewport, and then use a % of the screen. So it should render perfect fonts for each possible resolution...

Comment: Using ScreenViewport for your GUI/HUD is fine, you can use Table to make sure it's still correctly layout. You shouldn't scale assets, if you want to target two different resolutions then use two different sets of assets (generate the font twice, once for retina and once for lower resolutions).

Comment: Umm, but then how does Color Switch generate like so many different font sizes. Doesn't it load just 1 size and scale it down. Or does even a little scaling hurt? How do big games with many fonts sizes render this?

Comment: What's a Color Switch? Perhaps you can clarify your definition of "scaling", since you might mean something else.

Comment: Color Switch is a game, was just an example, that use's the same Font in like 5 different sizes and colors through the game. So do you think they load up 5 different size's or just 1 and scale it down. Because I just tried loading 4 different sizes fonts for resolution 1440 width, and well the game used to use 20mb ram, and it suddenly raised to 60mb. Which is not good because most RAM should be used by textures, but now textures seem to use 10x less.

Comment: You can use a single big font if you give it trilinear filtering (turn on mip maps and use MipMapLinearLinear for the min filter). They might be doing that or loading five different fonts. 50MB for fonts is kind of trivial for a game now a days. If your fonts are very big on your screen, you could look into distance field fonts. It allows a font to be scaled up without getting blurry, so you could load a single font and use it for all sizes.

Comment: Damn, so fonts do take alot more space than textures... Also as I need a texture size of 250, to work on 1440 width, it already takes 3x more time to load then a 2048x2048 atlas. At least I get it now why all the games use so much RAM, because I have never seen on mine any usage, until I used a font inside.

Comment: Yeah as @Tenfour04 says and I also said in the answer, there are ways to work around it. Note that the amount of RAM wont give you a good indication. Textures usually reside in VRAM not in RAM (actually they driver might swap them when needed, but that's usually not the case). The amount of RAM used depends on quite some factors, not the least your VM your application runs in. It might decide to allocate more memory or not free memory simply because it has enough RAM available. tl;dr; don't use RAM usage as indication of your asset size.

Comment: Just keeping a lookout anyway... Btw. last thing I wanted to ask is, can I generate MipMap for fonts if they are not of n^2 size. I mean would it then work on older phones that don't support OpenGl 2?

Comment: there is no reason your atlas should not be power of two sized, but if it is not POT sized for some reason then mipmaps is not guaranteed to work (e.g. it wont work on ios).

Comment: yeah the atlas is cool, but I was thinking about font.size, if it has to be set POT? (example: font.size = 16,32,64...)

Comment: no, font-size does not matter for generating mipmaps.

Comment: any ideas why this happens ? (http://imgur.com/Yl6hrst), but only if I have these trilinear filters. Letter's missing and white borders...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113385/discussion-between-jan-lovsin-and-xoppa).